# How do I access current block number within Benchmarks

Tags: benchmark, blocknumber

Trying to establish this function to be able to run to a specific block to test progressive extrinsics across blocks to simulate real execution within benchmarks:

````
    while System::block_number() < n {
        if System::block_number() > 1 {
            Proposals::on_finalize(System::block_number());
            System::on_finalize(System::block_number());
        }
        System::set_block_number(System::block_number() + 1);
        System::on_initialize(System::block_number());
        Proposals::on_initialize(System::block_number());
    }
}```

Unfortunately not able to compile with System within benchmark
````

Comment: For clarity sake, where are you trying to write this? For example you have access to `BlockNumber` here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/benchmarking/src/tests.rs#L94

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can jump to a block number using frame_system, just pass in the block number you want to jump to

e.g.

```
fn run_to_block<T: Config>(new_block: <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber) {
    frame_system::Pallet::<T>::set_block_number(new_block);
}
```

https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/HEAD/pallets/collator-selection/src/benchmarking.rs#L199

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which pallets are deployed in your *mocked* runtime.
In the easiest case you can just set the block number.
But often you also have to call the hooks of the deployed pallets.
In the way that you tried, other example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0a7e5ea46a17d71818eef8216e24eef0565bab57/frame/gilt/src/mock.rs#L125).
Could you maybe also include the error message and the mocked runtime if this does not answer your question?